# Prevent user from reading or copying file

Tags: windows

Imagine I have some content in file which I don't want anyone to read. Also encryption here doesn't help because I need to store the key anyway - and we have some problems with this.

Is it possible on windows to prevent user from reading and copying a file?

Update: Assume I have administrator rights. The file can be stored where it is needed. The user from which we want to protect this file - can have less privileges than Admin.

There is one thing though. There is software which should be able to read this file. PS who will run this software I am not sure yet though, maybe you can answer in both cases - assuming this user, or someone else runs the software

Comment: If you right click on a file and click "Properties" go to the "Security" tab and assign permissions for users.Not sure if you can stop copy though

Comment: @Harvey: I think that doesn't even prevent one from reading

Comment: Even from unchanging "Read" privileges?

Comment: @Harvey: Is there permission which prevents from reading? I don't know just. But copying remains issue?

Comment: Whether or not this makes any sense depends on the use case, but you can hide files/folders. That would prevent users from doing any of that, assuming that the user has no reason to believe files are hidden and or doesn't know how to show them.

Comment: You have read/write/modify/read&ex and special... but im not to sure if you can prohibit copying

Comment: Please specify the situation: What rights does the respective user have? What rights do you have? Where is that file stored?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: added details. Why downvotes?

Comment: @Joonas: Can we prevent her from showing hidden files?

Comment: If the user doesn't have permission to read the parent directory then the file doesn't exist as far as they are concerned.

Comment: @DavidPostill: What do you mean the parent directory? You mean directory where file/key is stored?

Comment: Yes. The directory containing the file and/or the key.

Comment: @DavidPostill: But there must be some software running which should be able to read that file - is that possible?

Comment: Now your question is not clear. You want to prevent a particular user from reading a file, but some software needs to read the file? Is the user running this software? What are you actually trying to achieve? Please [edit] and clarify your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill: did so, please see

Comment: You need to explain **what your real problem is** if you want help. **Why** are you tring to do this? There is no obvious solution. Please read [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: If this user is running the software then they can copy the file. If it some other user then changing the directory seciruty rights will solve your issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Can you elaborate your last comment - I could not follow. Yes it can be Admin starts the software. But how will other user be able to log in? Will not that shut down the software started by admin? Please elaborate on that. I am doing this to store sensitive information - key in that file.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing more about the software. Like I said your question is now very unclear.

Comment: @DavidPostill: This is just software which should run in continous manner - it could be Admin starts that. Then someone else might want to login right? From him/her I want to protect file from reading/copying - but software should still be able to use that file

Comment: Why don't you try changing the security rights and see if that works for your particular case? We are not here to try all possible options for you. You need to try things for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am showing this example with a folder, although it applies to any file type.

1. Select the file, right click and go to properties.
2. Go to the security tab & Click `edit`
3. Add a user's name with the `add` button, type the name of the user in the gray box, then hit `OK`. Now, DENY `Full Control` with the permissions for `...` tab
4. Hit yes to continue (If you get a warning message.)
   [image]

What happens when user `Beata` gets a bit to sneaky and tries to open the folder...
[image]

What happens when user `Beata` wants to copy this folder: (BTW user Beata is admin) :

[image]

Comment: can software access that folder?

Comment: Idk. It's like asking can a jungle be in a desert. Or in other words, most likely not, but who knows? Maybe mankind will do so one day.